# Implicit jsonFormat for java class

Tags: java, json, scala, akka, spray

I have a generated java class:

```
package cc.notsoclever.customerservice
public class Customer {
  protected String name;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
  }
}
```

(generated from WSDL to provide a SOAP interface, but it doesn't matter)

I want to connect to a JSON interface, so I need an implicit jsonFormat - I have already tried:

```
package cc.notsoclever.customerservice

object CustomerProtocol {
  import spray.json._, spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
  object Customer {
    implicit val format = jsonFormat(Customer.apply, "name")
  }
}
```

But it resulted in an error:

```
...value apply is not a member of object cc.notsoclever.customerservice.CustomerProtocol.Customer
[error]  Note: implicit value format is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]     implicit val format = jsonFormat(Customer.apply, "name")
[error]                                               ^
```

Is it possible to define an implicit format that will use public getters and setters? Or do I need to define marshalling manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spray's jsonFormatX helpers are for case classes. You can write a manual format or use a library like Jackson that's oriented towards Java Beans.